# dash_bootstrap_components.min.js not found when running Dash inside Django

Tags: django, plotly-dash

I am getting dash_bootstrap_components.min.js not found when i try to integrate Dash with Django.

Installed dash_bootstrap_components for Dash css

Dash Python:

```py
external_stylesheets = ['https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css']

app = DjangoDash('SIPPage', external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
```

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?